# Javascript Injection, unable to change value of a tag on website

Tags: javascript

I'm a beginner in javascript, and I am attempting to inject a phrase into the search bar of a website such as Facebook. I am using the developer tools and wrote

```
document.getElementsByName("q")[0].value = "myname";
```

According to Facebook's page source, they use

```
<input type="text" class="inputtext _586f" autocomplete="off" name="q" placeholder="Search Facebook" role="combobox" aria-label="Search Facebook" id="u_0_a" /><img class="_z-3 hidden_elem img" src="https://static.xx.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v2/yg/r/EG1P2rBTGkN.gif" alt="" id="u_0_b" width="16" height="16" />
```

for their main search bar. However, when I use my injection, nothing appears on the search bar. Does this have something to do with permissions, or am I making a mistake?

Comment: in reality you are typing in the div below the input

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the Facebook HTML, the search bar has the id `q`.
You can just get the value of it by using `document.getElementById().value`:

```
document.getElementById("q").value = "Hello";
alert(document.getElementById("q").value);
```

Or, if you want to use jQuery:

```
$("#q").val("Hallo");
alert($("#q").val())
```

Comment: This is what I thought, but I actually got the following error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null. I looked back at the id of the page source and found that it is actually "u_0_a", but even using this, I still got the same error